# chosen jquery not show correctly

Tags: nuget-package, jquery-chosen

I use chosen 1.2.0 from nuget. My `chosen.css` file contains class like `.chosen-container, .chosen-container`. When i call my dropdownlist class using .chosen() function. Resulted css class will be `chzn-container, chzn-container-multi`. It causes display ugly. but functionality work. I have no error in browser console.

When i check another sites, both generated markup and chosen.css contains `chzn-container, chzn-container-multi` classes only.

Comment: Nuget only installs css, i use chosen.jquery.js from some other folder(so version compatability problem). Why nuget not adds chosen.jquery.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuget adds only css. It is not add chosen.jquery.js. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The Nuget package named simply "chosen" does not, as the OP says, contain the .js.

You need to search for [Harvest.Chosen](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Harvest.Chosen/). Hopefully this will help someone in the future.